# How do I limit the number of referenced documents retrieved by Mongoid find()?

Tags: mongoid

I have a REST API route that should be limiting how many referenced "Thing" documents are included when showing a "Model" object.

Main model:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :things
end
```

Referenced Model:

```
class Thing
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :model
end
```

Model Controller:

```
def show
  # this should retrieve the first 30 "Things" that belong to the model we found
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])

  # I attempted this with no luck:
  # @model = Model.find(params[:id]).includes(:things).limit(30)
end
```

How can I retrieve the first N referenced records that are part of a model?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
@things = Thing.where(:model_id => @model.id).limit(30)
```

Comment: did it helped u in solving your problem??